# Is load balancing necessary in virtual environment (Hyper-V)?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I'm working on the design of the enviroment for an enterprise application. There is a plan to host the application in several VM's on one Hyper-V host.

The host server has limited CPU and memory capacity, distributed between VMs.

Is it a good idea to use load balancers in order to improve performance of the VM's hosted in a Hyper-V environment or is it better to allocate more resources to a VM?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what the application is, the OS, and how (together) they manage resources and deal with load.

It absolutely *can* be more beneficial to have several lower spec VM's than one high spec VM, but whether it's a 'good idea' for you simply depends.

Comment: For instance, I have following application components hosted under Windows 2008R2:

1. Web UI runned under IIS
2. Web Services hosted under IIS
3. Database

Chain of calls following:

UI -> Web Service -> Database

All components are planned to be deployed in several VMs, on one Hyper-V server.

Are there any benifits in intoducing load balancer between Web UI and services?

Comment: I'm not really up on the finer details of IIS WebApps, but add the detail to your question and I'm sure someone will be along who is!

Answer (score 0):

Its also worth bearing in mind that the main reason to use a load balancer is for high availability. They are great at monitoring your application servers and re-directing traffic if you have an application sever failure.

Better performance is a side effect, as for the single Hyper-V host... yes you will still probably get a performance boost but you would be better off utilizing two of them to increase your availability and performance. When it comes to the actual load balancer to use I would recommend either Kemp Technologies Hyper-V based appliance or the Loadbalancer.org [Hyper-V based load balancer](http://www.loadbalancer.org/downloads.php).

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [faq#promotion] carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.